# how to perform multiple aggregations on a single SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table with Three columns:

GEOID, ParcelID, and PurchaseDate.

The PKs are GEOID and ParcelID which is formatted as such:

```
GEOID     PARCELID     PURCHASEDATE
12345     AB123        1/2/1932
12345     sfw123       2/5/2012
12345     fdf323       4/2/2015
12346     dfefej       2/31/2022 <-New GEOID
```

What I need is an aggregation based on GEOID.
I need to count the number of ParcelIDs from last month PER GEOID
and I need to provide a percentage of that GEOID of all total sold last month.

I need to produce three columns:
GEOID Nbr_Parcels_Sold Percent_of_total

For each GEOID, I need to know how many Parcels Sold Last month, and with that Number, find out how much percentage that entails for all Solds.

For example:  if there was 20 Parcels Sold last month, and 4 of them were sold from GEOID 12345, then the output would be:

```
GEOID  Nbr_Parcels_Sold  Perc_Total
12345  4                   .2  (or 20%)
```

I am having issues with the dual aggregation.  The concern is that the table in question has over 8 million records.

if there is a SQL Warrior out here who have seen this issue before, Any wisdom would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using sub-query to count the sum

```
WITH data AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM [Table]
    WHERE
        YEAR(PURCHASEDATE) * 100 + MONTH(PURCHASEDATE) = 201505
)
SELECT 
    GEOID,
    COUNT(*) AS Nbr_Parcels_Sold,
    CONVERT(decimal(18,8), COUNT(*)) / 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data) AS Perc_Total
FROM 
    data t
GROUP BY
    GEOID
```

**EDIT**

To update another table by the result, use `UPDATE` under `WITH()`

```
WITH data AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM [Table]
    WHERE
        YEAR(PURCHASEDATE) * 100 + MONTH(PURCHASEDATE) = 201505
)
UPDATE target SET 
    Nbr_Parcels_Sold = source.Nbr_Parcels_Sold, 
    Perc_Total = source.Perc_Total
FROM 
    [AnotherTable] target
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            GEOID,
            COUNT(*) AS Nbr_Parcels_Sold,
            CONVERT(decimal(18,8), COUNT(*)) / 
                (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM data) AS Perc_Total
        FROM 
            data t
        GROUP BY
            GEOID
    ) source ON target.GEOID = source.GEOID
```

Comment: Some reserves about the "YEAR(PURCHASEDATE) * 100 + MONTH(PURCHASEDATE) = 201505". Applying function may effect the performance. Also, we may need check the COUNT(*) again 0 or we can get a divide by zero error. Do we need the GEOID=t.GEOID" in "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Table] WHERE GEOID = t.GEOID" ?

Comment: @Tim3880 There is impossible for the `COUNT(*)` in sub-query be 0, since the `GEOID` will always not null. But you reminded me if the % total may not be the whole sales in history, and also not by the `GEOID`, see edit

Comment: Eric, This query is great.  Can you surround this in an update sql?

Comment: @arcee123 Yes, you can put the `UPDATE` under the `WITH()` like the sample.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you are using SQL Server 2005 or later version, in which case you can get advantage of [windowed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) aggregation. In this case, windowed aggregation will allow you to get the total sale count alongside counts per `GEOID` and use the total in calculations. Basically, the following query returns just the counts:

```
SELECT
  GEOID,
  Nbr_Parcels_Sold   = COUNT(*),
  Total_Parcels_Sold = SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()
FROM
  dbo.atable
GROUP BY
  GEOID
;
```

The `COUNT(*)` call gives you counts per `GEOID`, according to the GROUP BY clause. Now, the `SUM(...) OVER` expression gives you the grand total count *in the same row as the detail count*. It is the empty OVER clause that tells the SUM function to add up the results of `COUNT(*)` across the entire result set. You can use that result in calculations just like the result of any other function (or any expression in general).

The above query simply returns the total value. As you actually want not the value itself but a percentage from it for each `GEOID`, you can just put the `SUM(...) OVER` call into an expression:

```
SELECT
  GEOID,
  Nbr_Parcels_Sold = COUNT(*),
  Percent_of_total = COUNT(*) * 100 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()
FROM
  dbo.atable
GROUP BY
  GEOID
;
```

The above will give you integer percentages (truncated). If you want more precision or a different representation, remember to cast either the divisor or the dividend (optionally both) to a non-integer numeric type, since SQL Server always performs integral division when both operands are integers.

Comment: Window function should be better than my suggestion, simple and optimal

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. It grabs the total sales into a variable then uses it in the subsequent query:

```
DECLARE @pMonthStartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @MonthEndDate DATETIME
DECLARE @TotalPurchaseCount INT

SET @pMonthStartDate = <EnterFirstDayOfAMonth>

SET @MonthEndDate = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @pMonthStartDate)

SELECT
  @TotalPurchaseCount = COUNT(*)
FROM
  GEOIDs
WHERE
  PurchaseDate BETWEEN @pMonthStartDate
               AND     @MonthEndDate 
SELECT
  GEOID,
  COUNT(PARCELID) AS Nbr_Parcels_Sold,
  CAST(COUNT(PARCELID) AS FLOAT) / CAST(@TotalPurchaseCount AS FLOAT) * 100.0 AS Perc_Total
FROM
  GEOIDs
WHERE
  ModifiedDate BETWEEN @pMonthStartDate
               AND     @MonthEndDate
GROUP BY
  GEOID
```

I'm guessing your table name is GEOIDs. Change the value of @pMonthStartDate to suit yourself. If your PKs are as you say then this will be a quick query.